# configure.h file and assembbler error in FFT from FFMPEG

Tags: eclipse, assembly, ffmpeg

i build a project on Eclipse using GCC Toolchain and arm-linux-gnueabi libraries
i have tow main issues using this codes attached (not my code, fft from ffmpeg with testcode to measure speed-error)
http://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/telligent-evolution-components-attachments/00-447-01-00-00-25-97-76/FFMPEG_5F00_FFT.zip

i have a C-code files with 2 .S files **asm.S** and **neon_fft.S** 
i am not a software engineer but i understood that i use function keyword from **asm.S** file to use it in **neon_fft.S** 
but it seems that project doesn't see the first file so i get the following error

```
Building file: ../src/fft_neon.S
Invoking: GCC Assembler
arm-linux-gnueabi-as -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/asm -o "src/fft_neon.o" "../src/fft_neon.S"
../src/fft_neon.S: Assembler messages:
../src/fft_neon.S:34: Error: bad instruction `function fft4_neon'
../src/fft_neon.S:50: Error: bad instruction `endfunc'
```

also how can i get right **configure.h** file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename ends with a capital S. By convention, this indicates that the assembler source needs to be processed by the C preprocessor. If you use arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc instead of arm-linux-gnueabi-as then the file should assemble successfully.

Comment: when i did that another error occurred  : Building file: ../src/asm.S
Invoking: GCC Assembler
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon  -o "src/asm.o" "../src/asm.S"
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [src/asm.o] Error 1

Comment: that is what i wrote in GCC Assembly  : arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon